# Update NSManagedObject on a app with VIPER architecture

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsobject, viper-architecture

On an app that performs VIPER architecture it's recomended to deal with entities with NSObject instead of NSManagedObject (Interactor). So a NSManagedObject is 'transformed' in a PONSO to work with.
The question is, if I modify attributes in a PONSO, how can I update Core Data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `NSManagedObject` instead of `NSObject`. This recommendation is not to be taken literally. In any case, `NSManagedObject` is a direct descendent of `NSObject`, so for all practical purposes it is just as good.

*As a side note, VIPER is a general architecture philosophy that has not gotten much traction due to the excessive granularity of its files and functions. I would recommend you reduce the "Massive View Controller" problem by structuring your code more functionally around these controllers, using VIPER as a good source of inspiration.*

Comment: This is not a good idea as one of the ideas behind VIPER is to separate the data persistence implementation from the rest of the application. If you now start passing around NSManagedObjects, all your code is dependant on CoreData and you get the problems mentioned by @Arkadi, too

Comment: Only that @Arkadi is wrong. Core Data **is** thread safe, and as it is the _de facto_ standard for persistence on iOS, my suggested solutions does not prevent separation of concerns while leveraging Apple's APIs for simplicity and performance.

Comment: I recently used CoreData quite heavily and I can ensure you that CoreData is still sporadically crashing when used on the wrong thread; with sporadically I mean crashes occur in the order of 1 in a million operations, but they do occur. Hence you need to wrap every operation in synchronised perform blocks.
Besides, even though CoreData is great, another db solution might be appropriate; especially when syncing to Android or Windows is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea. If you use any async code elements in your app and most of us do you should know that nsmanagedoject is not thread safe to pass around. You need to rethink your approach. If you use a core data backed app then you can store the managedobjectid in the ponso and use it to update the database while triggering a ui refresh after the database change